# Finding a sample to represent a known population

Tags: sampling, sample-size, randomness, representative

**Entire Population:** 30,000

**Known properties of population:** Age, gender, height, weight,

**Ideal representative sample size:** ???

This is for a mailing list test group selection.

**Problem constraints:**

1. Certain people can't be included in sample because they are on a do-not-mail list.
2. Sample group must have similar age, gender, height, and weight to entire population (known)

I imagine I have to randomly select members from the entire population that are not on the do-not-mail list and compare the average and variance of the sample compared to the entire population.  If the average and variance of the sample and entire population are similar, then I have a good sample?

I'm not sure if I'm on the right path or if there is an easier way.